# Equality of conditional mathematical expectations

Tags: probability-theory

I have a next task. Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables uniformly distributed on the interval $[-5,5]$. Prove that $E(X|X+Y) = E(Y|X+Y)$. So, I decided to solve this problem as follows. We know that $$E(X|X+Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{p_1(x,y)}{p_{X+Y}(z)}dx$$ and $$E(Y|X+Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{p_2(x,y)}{p_{X+Y}(z)}dx,$$ where $p_1(x,y)$ and $p_2(x,y)$ densities of joint distributions of vectors $(X, Y+X)$ and $(Y, Y+X)$, respectively. So, if $p_1(x,y) = p_2(x,y)$, then $E(X|X+Y) = E(Y|X+Y)$, right?

But the biggest problem for me is that I find it difficult to calculate these densities. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: The result is true for any i.i.d. random variables $X,Y$. Nothing to do with uniform distribution.

Comment: It looks obvious to me too, but I would like a more accurate proof, and proving the equality of densities of joint distributions of vectors (X, X+Y) and (Y, X+Y) looks like the easiest way, isn't it?

Comment: Random variables need not even have densities. I think you should look at the general measure theoretic  definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: The question has been answered many times (for a general distribution) , so you are unlikely to get an answer.